# How to inspect variables form interactive console in PyDev

Tags: eclipse, debugging, pydev, spyder, inspect

How can I run code in the Interactive Console in PyDev and see the created variables in the Variables view?

**I am looking for the same functionality available in Spyder**. If I am interactively running a script or just testing pieces, I would like o be able to see all the available shell variables and their respective values in the variables view.

I have already checked "Connect console to Debug Session" in Preferences > Pydev > Interactive console.

But when I run, say, a=1, the "Variables" view will be in italic for a moment and nothing appears there.

### ANSWER

Following Fabio's advice: I updated Pydev from v5.4 to 5.8. That did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's happening there.

For me, after checking `Connect console to Debug Session` in Preferences > PyDev > Interactive console, I do see created variables in the variables view.

Are you actually using the interactive console (i.e.: started with `Ctrl+Alt+Enter`)?

Can you show a screenshot with Eclipse on that situation?

Which PyDev version are you using?

Comment: Hi Fabio, I am starting with Ctrl+Alt+Enter. Here is a screenshot of the  [variables viewer](https://ibb.co/iowJaQ). PyDev version is [5.4](https://ibb.co/eQ0N25). I am one Eclipse Neon 4.6.2.

Comment: Is it possible for you to upgrade to the latest version? I think there was an issue with that which was fixed in a more recent release.